# PHP: Convert Extended Ascii file to UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, extended-ascii

i don't have any chance to get a valid utf-8 as output...

```
$fx = file_get_contents("Extended Ascii file.txt"); // example only has chr(129), but could be mixed Extended Ascii + UTF8

// not working:
//$fx = html_entity_decode($fx, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
//$fx = mb_convert_encoding($fx, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII');
//$fx = utf8_encode($fx);
//$fx = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $fx);

echo '"chr('.ord($fx[0]).')"=>"'.$fx[0].'"<br><br>'; // result: "chr(129)"=>"�"

$fx = strtr($fx, [chr(128)=>'Ç',chr(129)=>'ü',chr(130)=>'é',chr(131)=>'â',chr(132)=>'ä',chr(133)=>'à',chr(134)=>'å',chr(135)=>'ç',chr(136)=>'ê',chr(137)=>'ë',chr(138)=>'è',chr(139)=>'ï',chr(140)=>'î',chr(141)=>'ì',chr(142)=>'Ä',chr(143)=>'Å',chr(144)=>'É',chr(145)=>'æ',chr(146)=>'Æ',chr(147)=>'ô',chr(148)=>'ö',chr(149)=>'ò',chr(150)=>'û',chr(151)=>'ù',chr(152)=>'ÿ',chr(153)=>'Ö',chr(154)=>'Ü',chr(155)=>'ø',chr(156)=>'£',chr(157)=>'Ø',chr(158)=>'×',chr(159)=>'ƒ',chr(160)=>'á',chr(161)=>'í',chr(162)=>'ó',chr(163)=>'ú',chr(164)=>'ñ',chr(165)=>'Ñ',chr(166)=>'ª',chr(167)=>'º',chr(168)=>'¿',chr(169)=>'®',chr(170)=>'¬',chr(171)=>'½',chr(172)=>'¼',chr(173)=>'¡',chr(174)=>'«',chr(175)=>'»',chr(176)=>'░',chr(177)=>'▒',chr(178)=>'▓',chr(179)=>'│',chr(180)=>'┤',chr(181)=>'Á',chr(182)=>'Â',chr(183)=>'À',chr(184)=>'©',chr(185)=>'╣',chr(186)=>'║',chr(187)=>'╗',chr(188)=>'╝',chr(189)=>'¢',chr(190)=>'¥',chr(191)=>'┐',chr(192)=>'└',chr(193)=>'┴',chr(194)=>'┬',chr(195)=>'├',chr(196)=>'─',chr(197)=>'┼',chr(198)=>'ã',chr(199)=>'Ã',chr(200)=>'╚',chr(201)=>'╔',chr(202)=>'╩',chr(203)=>'╦',chr(204)=>'╠',chr(205)=>'═',chr(206)=>'╬',chr(207)=>'¤',chr(208)=>'ð',chr(209)=>'Ð',chr(210)=>'Ê',chr(211)=>'Ë',chr(212)=>'È',chr(213)=>'ı',chr(214)=>'Í',chr(215)=>'Î',chr(216)=>'Ï',chr(217)=>'┘',chr(218)=>'┌',chr(219)=>'█',chr(220)=>'▄',chr(221)=>'¦',chr(222)=>'Ì',chr(223)=>'▀',chr(224)=>'Ó',chr(225)=>'ß',chr(226)=>'Ô',chr(227)=>'Ò',chr(228)=>'õ',chr(229)=>'Õ',chr(230)=>'µ',chr(231)=>'þ',chr(232)=>'Þ',chr(233)=>'Ú',chr(234)=>'Û',chr(235)=>'Ù',chr(236)=>'ý',chr(237)=>'Ý',chr(238)=>'¯',chr(239)=>'´',chr(240)=>'≡',chr(241)=>'±',chr(242)=>'‗',chr(243)=>'¾',chr(244)=>'¶',chr(245)=>'§',chr(246)=>'÷',chr(247)=>'¸',chr(248)=>'°',chr(249)=>'¨',chr(250)=>'·',chr(251)=>'¹',chr(252)=>'³',chr(253)=>'²',chr(254)=>'■',chr(255)=>'nbsp']); 

echo '"chr('.ord($fx[0]).')"=>"'.$fx[0].'"<br><br>'; // result: "chr(195)"=>"�"
```

How to convert or remove � ?

**28.05.2020 Update: Solution found, thanks to Andrea Pollini!**

Some notes:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $fx); // IGNORE is broken in PHP since - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#108643 - use mb_convert_encoding
```

Here was my real problem (i figured it out later after many tests):

```
$P["T"] .= $text; // here was the problem, array is converting strings... (don't know why?)

changed to:

ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', "none"); // mb_convert_encoding set remove unknown
$P["T"] .= mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

Now it's working. But if somebody knows why arrays are converting strings and how to disable that, would be great. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first configure in order to discard extended characters

```
<?php
ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', "none");
?>
```

next you can use `mb_convert_encoding`

```
 mb_convert_encoding($fx, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($fx, "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true));
```

you can add the encoding you need in `mb_detect_encoding`

Comment: Tried it out, but it's not working. My strtr converts many characters, but there are still � left. Also $fx = preg_replace("/[^[:print:]ÄäÜüÖöß\r\n]/m", ' ', $fx); don't remove it... :(

Comment: where are you printing your string? I just try a simple echo that works in the CLI. I suppose you have to check your server settings. https://repl.it/@professorandrea/BriefDeeppinkExam